# SOAP API client request creation issue - addChildElement (org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR)

Tags: java, soap, soap-client

We have an issue with SOAP API client request creation while adding the child element to soap body(at highlight line). It is working fine in SOAP UI tool but not working in tomcat web application.
Please find below code and logs, suggest the root cause of the issue?
Logs are below:

```
SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
QName qname = new QName("test:doXMLProcess");
SOAPBodyElement bodyElemnt = body.addBodyElement(qname);
QName qname2 = new QName("Test_tag");
SOAPElement tag1 = bodyElemnt.addChildElement(qname2);
```

**org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
at org.apache.axiom.dom.DOMExceptionUtil.newDOMException(DOMExceptionUtil.java:65)
at org.apache.axiom.dom.NSUtil.validateNamespace(NSUtil.java:92)
at org.apache.axiom.dom.DOMDocumentSupport.ajc$interMethod$org_apache_axiom_dom_DOMDocumentSupport$org_apache_axiom_dom_DOMDocument$createElementNS(DOMDocumentSupport.aj:181)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.DocumentImpl.createElementNS(DocumentImpl.java:1)
at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPBodyImpl.addChildElement(SOAPBodyImpl.java:485)
at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPBodyImpl.addBodyElement(SOAPBodyImpl.java:315)